# Insert/Update the data in to database using ajax,page cannot be reload

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm inserting/updating data into a database using AJAX. The page cannot be reloaded. Here, my problem is, after the update the values without page reload values should be display below. See attached form screenshot for details.

Form:

```
 <div class="panel panel-default" >
    <div class="panel-heading row" id="first">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">First Name</div>
**here i am fetching values from database**
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 ellipsis"><?php echo $row->first_name; ?></div>
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 profile-edit"> <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit</div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
                    <label class="col-md-4">First Name</label>              
                    <div class="col-md-8"> 
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>" />
                        <input type ="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row->first_name; ?>"/></br>
                        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" style="width:70px;">
                        <!--                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="" id="">Save</button>-->
                        <button type="button" data-target="#collapseOne" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-warning cancel-name">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#data_form').on('submit', function (e) {
           var form_data = $(this).serialize();
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Profile_cntrl/supplier_basicinformation_edit',
               data: form_data,
               success: function (data)
               {

                   **here i want to display the database values first name**

               },
               error: function ()
               {
                   alert('failed');
               }
           });
           e.preventDefault();
       });

   });
</script>
```

This is the error below:

[image: Error Image]

Comment: paste your full code in Profile_cntrl controller

Comment: I corrected your introduction which is hardly more than a collection of word. Just try to make sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an id to the div, where you are displaying the name after fetching it from database.

```
<div class="panel panel-default" >
                                                <div class="panel-heading row" id="first">
                                                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">First Name</div>
**here i am fetching values from database**                                                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 ellipsis" id="name_div"><?php echo $row->first_name; ?></div>
                                                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                                                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 profile-edit"> <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit</div>
                                                    </a>
                                                </div>
                                                <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                                        <div class="row">
                                                            <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
                                                                <label class="col-md-4">First Name</label>              
                                                                <div class="col-md-8"> 
                                                                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>" />
                                                                    <input type ="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row->first_name; ?>"/></br>
                                                                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" style="width:70px;">
                                                                    <!--                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="" id="">Save</button>-->
                                                                    <button type="button" data-target="#collapseOne" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-warning cancel-name">Cancel</button>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
```

Then, use jquery to set the text of the div where you are displaying the first name upon success of Ajax post request

```
<script>
       $(document).ready(function () {

           $('#data_form').on('submit', function (e) {

               var form_data = $(this).serialize();

               $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Profile_cntrl/supplier_basicinformation_edit',
                   data: form_data,
                   success: function (data)
                   {

                       $('#name_div').text($("#first_name").val());

                   },
                   error: function ()
                   {
                       alert('failed');
                   }
               });

               e.preventDefault();
           });

       });
    </script>
```

Comment: above shown first_name,how to fetch the first_name and last_name and after click the save button button will not close..i attched one image @thrust

Comment: above i added the code from last_name..same i want output like first_name. @thrust

Comment: In your Profile_cntrl code, just send all the updated details from DB. Then in success of Ajax call, just get the last_name from data and set it in the same way as I am setting first_name. Here most important thing is that you should be sending last_name, first_name and all the other necessary details back from profile_cntrl. Post that, setting it in UI is not at all difficult.

Comment: k your code is working but one thing is after submit the values save button will not closing...above i attached image @thrust

Comment: What do you mean by save button not closing? Do you want to close the accordion?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a class or id where you want to show name and after ajax success you will call this id or class to show data .
Like this :

Form :

```
<div class="panel panel-default" >
                                                <div class="panel-heading row" id="first">
                                                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">First Name</div>
<div id="fname"> </div>
**here i am fetching values from database**                                                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 ellipsis"><?php echo $row->first_name; ?></div>
                                                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                                                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 profile-edit"> <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit</div>
                                                    </a>
                                                </div>
                                                <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                                        <div class="row">
                                                            <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
                                                                <label class="col-md-4">First Name</label>              
                                                                <div class="col-md-8"> 
                                                                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>" />
                                                                    <input type ="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row->first_name; ?>"/></br>
                                                                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" style="width:70px;">
                                                                    <!--                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="" id="">Save</button>-->
                                                                    <button type="button" data-target="#collapseOne" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-warning cancel-name">Cancel</button>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
```

//last name starts from here

```
  <div class="panel panel-default">
                                            <div class="panel-heading row">
                                                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">Last Name</div>
<div id="lname"> </div>
                                                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 ellipsis"><?php echo $row->last_name; ?></div>
                                                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
                                                    <div class="col-md-4  col-sm-4 col-xs-4 profile-edit"> <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit</div>
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                                <div class="panel-body">
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-2 text-center">

                                                            <label class="col-md-4">Last Name</label>             
                                                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                                                <input type="hidden" name="last_name" id="last_name" value="<?php echo $row->last_name; ?>" />
                                                                <input type ="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row->last_name; ?>"/></br>
                                                                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" style="width:70px;">
                                                                <!--                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>-->
                                                                <button type="button" data-target="#collapseTwo" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-warning cancel-name">Cancel</button>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
```

Script :

```
<script>


    $(document).ready(function () {

               $('#data_form').on('submit', function (e) {

                   var form_data = $(this).serialize();

                   $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Profile_cntrl/supplier_basicinformation_edit',
                       data: form_data,
                       success: function (data)
                       {
                        $('#fname').html(data.first_name);// data here fname
                        $('#lname').html(data.last_name); 


                           **here i want to display the database values first name**

                       },
                       error: function ()
                       {
                           alert('failed');
                       }
                   });

                   e.preventDefault();
               });

           });
        </script>
```

Comment: i  want to fetch a multiple values ex:fname,lname,sirname @Minar Mnr

Comment: that depends on your php script you can fetch multiple data and show them on your ajax . 
$('#fname').html(data.fname);
$('#lname').html(data.lname);

Comment: Can you provide me your data value in your script ?

Comment: first_name and last_name